# Stack Exchange for Android 4.x with ActionBarSherlock for 2.x only, why?

Tags: discussion, android-app

Why Stack Exchange for Android is using [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/), this makes app bigger and slower. The ActionBarSherlock adds action bar support to older android versions (Android 2.x), but Stack Exchange for Android requires Android 4.x! What is the reason?

> This (ActionBarSherlock) allows you to easily develop an application with an action bar for every version of Android from 2.x and up.

Android 4.x has [native support for Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html), Sherlock and Android [Support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) is not required!

> The ActionBar APIs **were first added in Android 3.0** (API level 11) but they are also available in the Support Library for compatibility with Android 2.1 (API level 7) and above.

Android Support Library + ActionBarSherlock increases the size of the application of 600kB+

[image: what is included screenshot]

Comment: What are you asking "why they went with ActionBarSherlock" or why is the app only supporting 4.0 and newer, rather than 2.0 any update?

Comment: Im asking "why they went with ActionBarSherlock", this is not necessary for android 4.0. Android 4 has native support for Action Bar

Comment: Ok, that's relevant info for your question.  Not everyone will know that tidbit.

Comment: *Meta Stack Overflow is currently offline for maintenance* for me now :) So wait

Comment: More context from someone who knows a little bit about Android development: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21384262/1288

Comment: Hmm, maybe SO authors also learns from this book? Joke ;)

Comment: It is possible that they are looking to support Android 2.x but have not gotten around to testing it or fixing lingering blocking issues for 2.x support.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When we first started we decided that due to our tech-savvy audience and the limited capacity we had internally to dedicate to it, we'd only support Android 4.0 and above at launch.

Obviously the next step here was to decide between meaning we'd *only* support Android 4.0 and above or we'd use nice helper libraries like ActionBarSherlock or ActionBarCompat to make our code be able to eventually easily downgrade to lower versions, while only needing to test 4.0 and above at the present.

Making the app work on lower versions of android is a [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) right now and since we're using ActionBarSherlock this lets us only have to deal with testing the android AP calls, low memory conditions, smaller screen density conditions, and vendor GUI differences found on lower levels of Android rather than having to rewrite all of our core logic too.

Comment: Android versions below 4.x is [less than 25% of all devices](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/4448/267) and shrinking. Do you really want to go that way?

Comment: @AlE. We've made no decision about how low we'll be going with Android version support. We've simply set ourselves up to be able to do that easily if we choose to do it. It's not like using ABS versus regular Android makes anything more difficult to do. Why not use it?

Comment: No one now sells android devices with 2.x. Android devices life time is something like 2 years. Also low memory and smaller screen can happen with Android 4 (especially with 4.4). It is much better to make good app with support for all new APIs.

Comment: @MariuszS Admittedly, I took [this photo](https://twitter.com/kerrick/status/341045138711269376/photo/1) seven months ago, but I'm pretty sure I can go to my nearest grocery store an get a 2.3 phone right now.

Comment: @BrianNickel Yes, my mistake ;) No one is producing android 2.x now ;)